# cardinality of the set $\{f \in Map_{surj}([1,6], [1,3]) | $there exists an $i \in [1,6] \backslash \{5\}$with $f(i)=f(5)\}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

What is the cardinality of the set

$\{f \in Map_{surj}([1,6], [1,3]) | $there exists an $i \in [1,6] \backslash \{5\}$with $f(i)=f(5)\}$ ?

I think that two values of the domain ($5$ and another one) are mapped to thes same value of codomain. 
Because of surjectivity the codomain keeps its cardinality:

$\{f \in Map_{surj}([1,6]\backslash f(i)\backslash(5), [1,3])\}$

and for the cardinality:

$|\{f \in Map_{surj}(|4|, |3|)\}| = 4! \cdot 
    \begin{Bmatrix}
      4\\
      3
    \end{Bmatrix} = 36$

Unfortunately this is wrong. The correct answer should be $450$.

**Question**: What am I understanding wrong here?

Comment: Is $[1, 6]$ an interval?

Comment: @PJK yes, it is

Comment: You have computed the number of surjective functions such that $f(5)=f(6)=f(i)=1$ for some $i \le 4$. Definitely not the set you wanted.

Comment: @Crostful can you give me an example how I should do it, please?

Comment: I think that the number you are looking for is equal $3\times \{f \in Map_{surj}([1,6]\backslash \{5\}, [1,3]) \}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about surjective maps $f:[6]\to[3]$ having the property that the value $f(5)$ is taken at least twice. It follows that the restriction of such an $f$ to $[6]\setminus\{5\}$ is still surjective. Conversely: Given any  surjective map $f:\bigl([6]\setminus\{5\}\bigr)\to[3]$ you can choose $f(5)$ in three ways in order to obtain a map of the requested kind.

The number of surjective maps between finite sets is counted by the Sylvester numbers of the second kind. In the case at hand this number is $\>3!\cdot S(5,3)=6\cdot 25$. It follows that the number you are after is $\ =6\cdot 25\cdot 3=450$.